# Why do we have to put 'hex' at the end of this function? Buffer.from('key' , 'hex')

Tags: web3js, transactions, raw-transaction

I know that this line of code: `Buffer.from('key', 'hex')` Converts a string into its binary representation. My question is: what does adding the 'hex' at the end do? I am confused, since the key is already in hexa-decimal, why would we want to specify that if the function can work on any string?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

Comment: `key` is a string which is by default encoded in UTF-8, regardless of whether that string looks like a number represented in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string can consist of an integer in any basis, that's the reason you have to include the basis, so the integer within is interpreted properly. Examples:

'01' Basis 2, or 'binary'

'01234567' Basis 8, or 'octal',

'0123456789' Basis 10, or 'decimal',

'0123456789ABCDEF' Basis 16, or 'hexadecimal'

Example that shows why it is important to specify the representation:

We want to intepret the following number as an octal number: 42

Buffer(42, 5) would create a byte array from the number 22<sub>10</sub>

Buffer(42, 8) would create a byte array from the number 34<sub>10</sub>

Buffer(42, 10) would (obviously) create a byte array from the number 42<sub>10</sub>

note that the string representation for the basis can differ in the Buffer API ('hexadecimal' is only 'hex' in Buffer), checkout the Buffer documentation for more information (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

btw. please post only Ethereum related questions in this stackexchange, use stackoverflow for language specific questions.